# How do I fix a .bashrc that makes it impossible to log into a remote server?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have just got an account to access a remote server(not root), and I was trying to replace the default bash with zsh.

Then awkward thing happened, I wrote something like `exec zsh` in bashrc, hoping that it can replace bash with zsh everytime I log in. However, I mistakenly misspelled the path of zsh, now every time I want to ssh my server, it will say `.bashrc: line 28: exec: zsh: not found` and end the session, I cannot log in my account anymore...

Is there a way to fix it without bothering the administrator? Because it's weekend and I need to use the remote server...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest doing this the right way and using `chsh` going forward. The `exec zsh` hack in `.bashrc` is going to mess up any scripts that try to run with `bash -li` to get dotfiles sourced in, f/e.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I think I still do not get it, I tried `ssh myhost -p 20022 'mv .bashrc .bashrc.old'` in my terminal, but it is still not working. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: "Not working" meaning what, exactly? Does running the command you quoted above result in the error in question itself, or does it simply not stop the error from happening again later?

Comment: It is still giving the error `.bashrc: line 28: exec: zsh: not found`.@CharlesDuffy

Comment: Which "it"? The ssh command I gave you, or the regular ssh command *after* you run that one?

Comment: If it's the former, one additional trick to avoid classification as an interactive shell is to ensure that at least one of stdin or stderr is not a TTY, as follows: `ssh -T -p 20022 myhost 'echo $-; set -x; mv .bashrc .bashrc.old' </dev/null`

Comment: Hi, this is what happened when I run it in the zsh on Mac... `ssh -T -p 20022 myhost 'echo $-; set -x; mv .bashrc .bashrc.old' </dev/null
myhost's password: 
~/.bashrc: line 28: exec: zsh: not found`

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if maybe your remote system is setting `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` to point to your `.bashrc`, which would force it to be executed even for noninteractive shells. Unfortunately, it's not behaving to documented spec (*or* identically to the systems I've locally tested with); without actually investigating the remote machine and figuring out how its behavior has been modified from stock defaults, there's not much more I can do here.

Comment: Actually -- one thing you *can* still try is running a `sftp` session and doing the rename from there.

Comment: I will try `sftp`, thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Just want to share with you, I pressed control+c as soon as I logged into the server so that the `~/.bashrc` was not loaded, and I succeeded without over 1 million attempts, how lucky :D

Answer (score 5):

Use `sftp` to rename the file. This will work so long as sshd is configured to use its internal sftp server implementation, as opposed to an external subsystem.

<sub>Marked community wiki as this is a known-off-topic question (not being ["unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); in the future, questions about interacting with a UNIX system as an end-user, as opposed to writing software for same, should be asked at [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not StackOverflow.</sub>

Comment: SFTP will work (provided the server allows it). Using the command line won't work if bash is the login shell, due to a bizarre feature of bash: when bash is a login shell and its parent process is sshd, it reads `.bashrc`.

Comment: You're right -- that *is* documented. How it's *desirable* behavior in the case where there's no TTY I don't know, but... well, learned something.

Comment: I don't think SFTP will work. The OpenSSH server uses a shell instance to launch the sftp server process.

Comment: @Kenster, ...it does? **Really?** That seems like an astonishingly bad idea, particularly given bash's behavior with respect to invoking `.bashrc` when sshd is the parent process -- the whole point of sftp-only services is to avoid the user from running arbitrary code, and if they can upload their own dotfiles and have them executed when an sftp connection is created, that defeats sftp-only services-as-a-security-measure.

Comment: Well, come to think of it, it depends on how the server is set. It could use [internal-sftp or the external sftp-server program](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/6474).

Comment: @Kenster, yup -- I was reading through the source and coming to that conclusion myself.